# CakePHP: variables are cleared when next/privous is clicked

Tags: cakephp, paginator

I have an action from a controller that provides a result variable via `$this->set('found_products', $data);`. The view page `products.ctp` is divided into two sections:

1. On top, a form where a user enters a string to search `$found_products` is set for the view.
2. Below it, paginated results that is displayed only if `$found_products` is set. i.e. `if (isset($found_products))` is true.

When `if (isset($found_products))` is true, I get the first page displayed below the form with the search string already in the text box. The URL for this is `myapp/controller/products`.

The problem occurs when I move into the next pages. The URL becomes `myapp/controller/action/products:2` and none of the variables used under `myapp/controller/products` exist. It looks like moving onto a new page clears all variables.. Below is the code I'm using for paging, and I have no reroute rules written for this. How do I solve this issue?

```
        <div class="paging">
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ' . __('previous', true), array(), null, array('class'=>'disabled'));?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers();?>        
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next', true) . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled'));?>
        </div>
```

I've tried to work around this using $_SESSION in the action (`products`) and setting this for the view, but when I did this, `$this->Paginator' no longer worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $this->Paginator->options to preserve the passed arguments in the pagination links. Try this code

```
<div class="paging">
    <?php $this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ' . __('previous', true), array(), null, array('class'=>'disabled'));?>
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers();?>        
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next', true) . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled'));?>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. On my first page of paginated result, the URL is `myapp/controller/products`, and this URL has no argument. `$this->passArgs` is also empty.. Do you have another idea?

Comment: I think you forgot to mention the method you are using to submit the form. If you are using 'POST', then this method will not work because the search parameters are not available in the url string. The above solution works for the 'GET' method. But if you want to use 'POST', then you'll have to use javascript to make each pagination link submit a form with the search string and the page number. But IMHO you should consider using the 'GET' method, because it will allow you to save the result as bookmark as well.

Comment: Hm.. you're right. Thanks! It's easier for me right now to use GET. I'll dwell into using POST and doing redirects later, but I finally figured out how to make this work. I did change the options array a little from what you have up there to --> `$this->Paginator->options['url']['?'] = $this->passedArgs;`, so that the next page followed the URL needed to moved onto the next or previous page.

Comment: Haven't gotten the column sorting to work yet, however. I'm looking into that.